# Is this the correct setting for the following volume?

Tags: calculus

LEt $\Omega = \{ 1 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 4 \} $, and let $f(x,y,z) = z^2$, then

does

$$ \int_\Omega f = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_1^2 r^2 \cos^2(\phi)r^2 \sin( \phi) \, dr \, d \theta \, d\phi $$

is the true?

Comment: Why do you have $\sin^2(\phi)$?

Comment: the jacobian of the change of variables? I am using spherical coorditanes

Comment: It should be $\sin(\phi)$.

Comment: you are right! fixed it ! the limits of integration are correct?

Comment: The rest is correct.